# jQuery navigation bar failing on click.

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have some HTML:

```
<div id="navigationBar" style="">
  <div id="sheight" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #dee5e8; width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <div class="menuItem" style="height: 10px;">
    </div>

    <div id="selectedMenuItem" class="menuItem" style="">
      <div class="tIcon" style="">
        <img src="images/iconeducationtransparent.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="menuText" style="">
        Education
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="menuItem">
    <div class="tIcon">
      <img src="images/iconfastcashtransparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="menuText">
      Fast Cash
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and some jQuery:

```
jQuery("#navigationBar").click(function(event) {

  //console.log( jQuery(event.target).parents('.menuItem').html() );
  var tt = jQuery(event.target).parents('.menuItem');
  console.log( jQuery.trim(tt.children('.menuText').html()) );
  var sNav = jQuery.trim(tt.children('.menuText').html());


  switch(sNav)
  {
    case "Education":
      alert("Eduction");
      break;
    case "Fast Cash":
      alert("Fast Cash");
      break;
    case "Credit Cards":

      alert("Credit Cards");
      break;
    case "Legal Help":

      alert("Legal Help");
      break;
    case "New Car":

      alert("New Car");
      break;
    case "Gov. Aid":

      alert("Gov Aid");
      break;
    case "Health Care":

      alert("Health Care");
      break;  
    case "Debt Help":

      alert("Debt Help");
      break;
    case "Auto Ins":

      alert("Auto Ins");
      break;
    case "Credit Score":

      alert("Credit Score");
      break;
    case "Paid Surveys":

      alert("Paid Surveys");
      break;
    case "Specials":

      alert("Specials");
      break;
    case "Debt Help":

      alert("Deby Help");
      break;  
    default:

  }

});
```

It appears to work about 99% of the time in which case I get the text of the `.menuItem` out to the console. However in some cases there is a blank being spit out to the console. I theorize at this point that sometimes the actual parent element `.menuItem` is actually being clicked in which point the script fails. Does anyone know if that could be right? I would like the script to handle whatever exception is occurring but first I have to know what it is.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the `event.target` can show a different element.

I would bind it to the element you want and use `$(this)` like:

```
jQuery("#navigationBar .menuItem").click(function(event) {

    var tt = $(this);
    var sNav = jQuery.trim(tt.children('.menuText').text());
    console.log(sNav);
    alert(sNav);

});
```

This way `this` should be the `menuItem` because that’s what we are binding.

Comment: My DiV's in this case have rounded corners but its in the CSS only... The rounded corners make it possible to select the parent only in this case since there is a small space there for the fillets.

Comment: Your welcome, Yep any space outside the inner div's would cause this.